# Efficiently store large table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres 11 that contains ~500 million rows and is approx 57 GB in total size, as shown by the following query.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('my_table')) AS data_size,
pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('idx_my_table')) AS index_size,
pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('my_table') + pg_relation_size('idx_my_table')) AS data_plus_index_size,
pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('my_table')) AS total_relation_size;
```

[image]

The table has the following structure:

```
create table my_table
(
    id bigserial not null
        constraint pk_my_table
            primary key,
    id_from integer not null,
    id_to integer not null,
    distance numeric not null
);

create index idx_id_from_to
    on my_table (id_from, id_to, distance);
```

The table is read from very frequently. The data in the table does not change very often at all and the index `idx_id_from_to` makes querying very quick.

What I would like to know is if there are more effecient ways (different data types etc.) to store this table to cut down the size?

I often have to replicate this table elsewhere and the size makes that a long process, even using dump tools.

Comment: The answer depends on the data stored in the table. Can you be certain that you never have an `id` over 2147483647? what are the value ranges for `id_from` and `id_to`? Do you need an exact number for `distance`? What is the required precision? All in all, don't expect substantial space savings.

Comment: `distance` can be a decimal/float e.g. 1.2465. I'm pretty sure its safe to say `id` won't exceed 2147483647. `id_from` and `id_to` would be in the range of 0 up to 200,000

Comment: `pg_relation_size('idx_my_table')`  You don't seem to have an index by that name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the potential savings:

- use `integer` for `id` if you are absolutely certain that the value will never exceed 2147483647
- use `real` for `distance` if you can live with a few digits of precision

Depending on how long the `numeric` was, that may save you some 6 or 10 bytes per row, perhaps around 4 GB of space. I am not sure if that is worth the trouble and the loss in precision.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql has a high row overhead, both per table row and per index entry.  There isn't much you can do about this overhead while using PostgreSQL's ordinary heap access method.  Have you looked into some extensions like timescaledb, or cstore_fdw?